# Telegram bot error - "Bad Request: BUTTON_URL_INVALID"

Tags: python, api, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Write bot for telegram on python and use [PyTelegramBot](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#reply-markup) lib.

Code:

```
markup_city = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
b1  = 
telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Москва',callback_data='Москва')
markup_city.add(b1)

bot.send_message(message.chat.id,texts.strat_message,reply_markup=markup_city)
```

And Error:

> `A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
>   [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: BUTTON_URL_INVALID"}']`

its very strange error... I don't understand what is.

How do you think, what it can be?

Comment: https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.inlinekeyboardmarkup.html Take a look at. I think that you are probably getting something wrong in InlineKeyboardMarkup() parameters

Comment: your are sending 2 rows of buttons? or one?

Comment: I agree with @tashakori's comment. I think you should add one more button or set row_width = 1

Comment: Does not work. Tried set the value of 1 and 2 buttons to do. The reason is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we can see in [Bot API docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api), [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) have an optional parameter *url*. There is no problem to skip it in the request as you are doing, but implementation of *InlineKeyboardButton* type in the library you have used may be a cause of such behavior. Take a part in contributing with this issue on the project page at GitHub and it will be helpful for many people.